# Update MS Access after editing bound listbox contents

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, listbox

I created a listbox bound to a datatable in C# connected to an MS Access database.

The idea was to display the contents of the table on the listbox and by selecting each one, it would then display the other values on textboxes all over the form. I was able to do just that. My next problem would be to update the database when editing the values in the textboxes. Now what I did was to create an update button which will then update the values in the listbox and then calling the Update() function for the dataAdapter the listbox is using but it doesn't seem to be affecting the table. My code is below.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstEmployees.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        dEmployeesTable.Rows[lstEmployees.SelectedIndex].BeginEdit();
        dEmployeesTable.Rows[lstEmployees.SelectedIndex]["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
        dEmployeesTable.Rows[lstEmployees.SelectedIndex].AcceptChanges();
        dAdapter2.Update(dEmployeesTable);
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything? I've tried this with datagridviews and it works fine including the editing and deleting. Not sure why it doesn't work on listboxes.

I've tried looking around and searching stackoverflow and other sites but i can't find anything close.

Answer (score 0):

When using [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx), the order of execution is as follows:

- The values in the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) are moved to the parameter values.
- The [OnRowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.onrowupdating.aspx) event is raised.
- The command executes.
- If the command is set to FirstReturnedRecord, then the first returned result is placed in the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx).
- If there are output parameters, they are placed in the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx).
- The [OnRowUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.onrowupdated.aspx) event is raised.
- [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges.aspx) is called.

so remove the line of             `dEmployeesTable.Rows[lstEmployees.SelectedIndex].AcceptChanges();` and try again

`AcceptChanges` commits changes to the dataset or datatable. All added and modified rows
become `"Unchanged"`.

when you call `Update (..)`, the data adapter doesn't
find any modified rows to update. `Update ()` calls `AcceptChanges ()`internally.